# Change inspiring quote in html like Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

In Laravel welcome page there is `<div class="quote">{{ Inspiring::quote() }}</div>` this function which changes quote dynamically.
Is it possible to implement this function in a HTML page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. try this

```
<html>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        var arr = ["Its Amazing","The Power to do more","Try This","You can do this"];
        var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

    </script>


    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rand;
    </script>
</html>
```

demo is here https://jsfiddle.net/bgg3mman/